# What is better way to maintain AOSP source code in git repository

Tags: git, android-source, git-mirror

I am new to git.
We are more then 15 people working on same project.
May I know, what is the better approach to maintain AOSP source code in git repository.
I am trying to create setup Git mirror or repo.
Generally ,how people will maintain AOSP source code.

Comment: Here is described how the AOSP works: https://source.android.com/setup

Comment: No offense, but do you actually plan to modify the AOSP code? If you have no experience with git, that will be a super-painful experience. Either find a smaller project to work on or find someone who already has git experience, because the learning curve combined with the scope of AOSP means you'll have many, many failures before you have your first success.

Comment: yes, I am planing to modify the AOSP code in framework and HAL level.

Comment: @coder were you able to setup your repository, if yes can you please share the steps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AOSP is split over many separate Git repositories and those are managed using a tool called [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading).

Think of `repo` as a manager for multiple Git repositories. It manages checking out the many Git repositories that make up AOSP and you can use it to switch branches (which in turn switches each underlying Git repository to the appropriate branch).

Answer (score 4):

There is one more way.
You could take all the code of the AOSP (inc. the kernel) and put it in a big fat git repository.

Its not the best idea, however surprisingly it works well for many phone manufacturers.

Why?
Because de-facto Android production code is so tightly coupled between its repositories, and vendor parts are usually tag-specific..

It means however you'll be cherry-picking quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Google repo is the best option IMHO. However 3 out of 4 of the companies I'm collaborating with, they have a single, flat, huge git repo. It takes more time and space to creating branches and many other git operations but it works ok